# Remove after a particular String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have some text content

```
atxtCtnt = "Helow Hay How Are You"
```

if **Hay** exists I need to remove **Hay How Are You**

I did it like this:

```
var atxtCtnt = "Helow Hay How Are You",
txt = atxtCtnt.substring(atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay"));
atxtCtnt = atxtCtnt.replace(txt , "");
alert(atxtCtnt );
```

Please help me in better way without RegExp

Comment: If one or more similar string "Hay" exist then how you will process

Comment: in my code i'll have only one "Hay"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the sub string from 0 to the index. But only if the index is more than 0 (The term "Hay" exists in the text). Like this

```
var atxtCtnt = "Helow Hay How Are You";
var index = atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay");
var newText = (index < 0) ? atxtCtnt : atxtCtnt.substring(0, index);
alert(newText);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Regex...
I think this will make your code a little bit shorter

```
a = atxtCtnt.indexOf('Hay');
atxtCtnt = a >=0?atxtCtnt.substring(0,a):atxtCtnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

this is what i did

```
var atxtCtnt = "Helow Hay How Are You",
txt = atxtCtnt.substring(0, atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay"));
alert(txt );​
```

thank u for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
atxtCtnt = atxtCtnt.substring(0, atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay"));
```

**Edit**: To account for if `Hay` isn't there:

```
atxtCtnt = atxtCtnt.substring(0, atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay") === -1 ? atxtCtnt.length : atxtCtnt.indexOf("Hay"));
```

Comment: This will fail if there is no Hay in the string

Comment: @mplungjan - Didn't think of that! Have posted the correction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is better solution than this with substrings, but you can also try this:

```
atxtCtnt.split('Hay')[0]
```

You can remove whitespace at the end of "Helow " like this:

```
atxtCtnt.split('Hay')[0].trim()
```

Comment: except in browsers that do not support .trim()

Answer (score 1):

```
var word = "Hay";
var a = "Helow Hay How Are You";
var b = a.split(word); // now you have two parts b[0] = Helow and b[1] = How Are You
document.body.innerHTML=b[0];
```

Comment: you can also split array of words then can join them!